# Database can't be opened exception

Tags: android, sqlite, exception

```
package com.thenweboston.zaika;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class Fourth extends Activity
{
    private EditText ed1,ed2;
    private Button b;
    private TextView tv;
    private SQLiteDatabase db;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.login);
            ed1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.EditTxt);
            ed2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.EditTxt1);
            b=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button5);
            tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtView);
            b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
            {
                public void onClick(View v)
                {
                    String s=ed1.getText().toString();
                    String y=ed2.getText().toString();
                    if(TextUtils.isEmpty(s))
                    {
                        ed1.setError("Please fill your username");
                    }
                    else if(TextUtils.isEmpty(y))
                    {
                        ed2.setError("Please fill your password");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        check();
                    }
               }
          });
       }
    public void check()
    {
          db=SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase("/data/com.thenweboston.zaika/databases/Hotels",null,SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
        String query="Select * from hot where email='s' and password='y'";
        Cursor c=db.rawQuery(query,null);
        if(c.getCount()>0)
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"true",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        else
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"wrong credentials",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

I am trying to create a login page where It will not allow users with wrong credentials to get access to the home page.Here when I am trying to run the code I am getting "Database can't be opened" Exception.

Answer (score -1):

//The Android's default system path of your application database.

```
private static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/YOUR_PACKAGE/databases/";
```